# Possible number based cipher… but which one?

Tags: puzzle-identification

Here's a sequence of numbers:

> 133, 173, 30, 133, 176, 160, 171, 63, 137, 176, 160, 60, 177

I'm sure they are an important part of a puzzle I'm trying to solve which I found hidden in an image - but I cant identify the cipher used.

Does anyone here have any ideas?

Comment: Is this a part of an ongoing competition?

Comment: Nah - just a geocaching related puzzle

Comment: The more context you give, the more likely it is that someone will find a clue.

Comment: Unfortunately there wasn't much to go on... However the title of the puzzle was called 'three in one' which I expect maybe a hint.

Comment: Usually with geocaching puzzles the decoded string will be map coordinates